# centos6 / apache2.2 / mod_deflate: Not working

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6, mod-deflate, deflate

I have a server with **Centos6**, **Apache2**.2, `mod_deflate`, `mod_filter` etc enabled.. But I dont see any compression. I have tried all combinations of filter and mod commands that is on the internet for mod_deflate. It only works on local machine but not on server.

Furthermore, I see that the **apache environment** on server has the following:
`HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = gzip`

While on local its, `gzip,deflate,sdch`

So how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You mention you have tried all commands you can find could you be more specific on what commands?

Have you tried `sudo /sbin/service httpd restart`?

Comment: well, I have had httpd restart every time I made a change to the apache settings...

Comment: Can you post your config?

Comment: from which file exactly do you want me to give you the config? The `httpd-vhosts.conf` is not being used, it has default example entries. `httpd.conf` has a lot of config lines, but I cant post the whole of it. This file also includes many configs from `usr/local/apache/conf/includes`..there was no `deflate.conf`, I put one myself, but its not getting used...